# App engine -- how to handle shutdown hooks now that backends are deprecated?

Tags: google-app-engine

I noticed that the shutdown hook has been deprecated:

[Runtime API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/runtimeapi)

I moved my app from using backends to modules, but obviously App Engine will still shutdown instances sometimes. How should we handle that going on because I don't see any documentation in the Modules section?

Thanks.